# What is the difference between making a CPI using Anchor's CpiContext::new_with_signer vs invoke_signed?

Tags: anchor, cpi

Could someone explain the difference and if there are there any additional benefits to using `CpiContext::new_with_signer` vs `invoke_signed` when making a CPI in an Anchor program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`invoke_signed` is not part of Anchor, but rather part of Solana SDK itself. It is used to make CPI calls.

`new_with_signer()` creates and returns an Anchor CPI context. This context gathers all the necessary info to make a CPI call but it does not actually make the call itself.

That part is done by the CPI methods that Anchor generates, e.g. `my_program::cpi::my_instruction()`. This method receives the context and will actually call `invoked_signed`.

You can see this in the macro's [implementation](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/93332766f13e86efbe77c9986722731742317ede/lang/syn/src/codegen/program/cpi.rs#L101).

Comment: This is correct. It might be worth noting that the `anchor expand` command helps visualize this concept by showing that invoke_signed is indeed called eventually